# twitter-bootstrap based toscawidget

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, turbogears, toscawidgets

Is there any project that use twitter-bootstrap in toscawidget templates? imo turbogears project really can benefit from twitter-bootstrap to create a high quality interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ToscaWidgets2 project has a bootstrap based version of its widgets, give a look at [tw2.bootstrap](https://github.com/toscawidgets/tw2.bootstrap)

Answer (score 2):

actually it is very easy to use twitter bootstrap with toscawidgets. there are two ways for this.

1) inject bootstrap stylesheets and other required files in your templates and bootstrap styles the forms. you can use javascript to do some magic if you need.

2) [toscawidgets use templates to render widgets and forms](https://bitbucket.org/toscawidgets/tw.forms/src/6df9d762af84/tw/forms/templates). you can create a new template for your forms and modify them according to bootstrap[. TurboGears docs have a sample for this](http://turbogears.org/2.1/docs/main/ToscaWidgets/forms.html#customizing-with-css-and-form-templates).

hope this helps.

Comment: If you see toscawidget form templates, we couldn't just add twitter-bootstrap lib, the html structure need to be reworked. This kind of modified library/project that I would like to know if it exists anywhere